# Angular - how can I update a field in my BehaviorSubject store value in a function without calling getValue

Tags: angular, subscribe, behaviorsubject

I'm writing an app with Angular 9.

I decided to use an rxjs store with a BehaviorSubject for simple state management.

This is what my code is trying to do: I have some user profiles with permissions that users get when they login. I want to store it in local storage so it will persist when they close the app. I want to load the data and be able to change the currently selected profile. I want this data to be available in a variety of places in my app.

Here is my code sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-state-management-get-set

*Please press the 'add profile' button on the demo app*

Store code snippet:

```
export class PersonaService {

    private readonly data: BehaviorSubject<IPersonaData>;
    public readonly sharedData: Observable<IPersonaData>;

    constructor() {
        this.data = new BehaviorSubject<IPersonaData>(null);
        this.sharedData = this.data.asObservable() as Observable<IPersonaData>;
    }
```

I have a function in my code:

```
public setSelectedPersonaIndex(newIndex: number): void {

    const temmpData: IPersonaData = this.data.getValue();

    temmpData.currentPersonaIndex = newIndex;

    this.data.next(temmpData);

    localStorage.setItem(Constants.KEYS.defaultPersonaIndex, newIndex.toString());
}
```

What I want to do is to only update ONE field in my BehaviorSubject store. E.g.
My stored data looks like this:

```
const example: IPersonaData = {
    currentPersonaIndex: null,
    personas: []
};
```

I only want to update the currentPersonaIndex in my BehaviorSubject store and not the other values and then save that new result.

It was mentioned to me that calling getValue could be the incorrect approach as it will affect the subscribers. Is that true?

How can I update the value without calling getValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you want to update I would recommend spreading then nexting;

   ```
   const tempData: IPersonaData = {...this.data.getValue(), currentPersonaIndex: newIndex};

   this.data.next(tempData);
   ```

If you call `next()` on `this.data` all subscribers will get notified.
If you want to optimize this use rxjs `distinctUntilChanged` / `distinctUntilKeyChanged` on each subscriber.

My tip for you:

- if you want a lightweight state management have a look at [rx-angular-state](https://github.com/BioPhoton/rx-angular)
- watch Michael Hladkys (library author) talks on youtube.

Comment: Does calling getValue() affect subscribers that already got it?